# Why does Logic 8 lose the DAW controller mappings from my M-Audio Axiom 49 between sessions?

Tags: midi, logic-pro

This is terribly frustrating. I spend 20 minutes setting up the controller surface mappings in Logic so that the Play key maps to the Play/Pause command in Logic, faders map to channels, and so on, only to have Logic lose those settings the next time I start a project.

I've tried saving a a project template after making the mappings and opening the next new project using this template, but the mappings are still gone.

Is there a way to make the MIDI-controller-to-DAW-function mappings persist from session to session? I'm trying to avoid bringing along both the Axiom (for performance input) and my Frontier Design's AlphaTrack when I travel with my laptop rig. Do it all from just the Axiom.

Edit: still happens even if the Axiom is left on between sessions. [Apparently this is a Logic 8 issue](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2402208?threadID=2402208) but the workarounds suggested in that thread aren't working for me. Anyone have any more insight on this for me? Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This often happens when you launch Logic before the Axiom is powered on.  This causes the MIDI Input port settings under Preferences -> Control Surfaces -> Controller Assignments to get reset to an incorrect value.

The good news, if this is what's happening in your case, is that you don't have to relearn all the mappings, just go through and change the MIDI Input port setting for each learned parameter back to the correct port.  The bad news is that there's not a permanent fix yet (that I know of), unless you count "always start up your Axiom before you launch Logic".

Comment: Ah interesting. I hadn't correlated starting Logic before the Axiom. It's true: I'll do one session in Logic with the Axiom and then later do another session without the Axiom attached. I thought it was losing the mappings every time but now I'll have to double check that. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't the case. I can leave the Axiom on, connected, and I'll still lose all my MIDI mapping settings betwen sessions. It's maddening really.